# Imported Rigify rig is broken

Tags: rigging, export, import, rigify

I created and exported a functioning rigify rig (as seen in the image to the right). However, importing the .fbx back into the project, it appears broken (as seen in the image to the left). I have the rigify plugin enabled and have python scripts allowed to automatically run. I'm on blender 3.1.2. How can I fix the rig? [image]

Comment: stepping back a bit: why are you reimporting the fbx and not using the original working rig?  FBX export will break assumptions that rigify makes and if you reimport it into the same blend file you will have problems because rigify needs extra steps to support multiple rigs in the same blend file.

Comment: @MartyFouts I wanted to check to see if the rigify rig would export/import properly. I've tested this by importing the rig into a new blend project as well (rigify addon enabled, python scripts set to automatically run). The results were the same as it still appeared broken.

Comment: Well, you've found out that it won't.  Rigify requires a python rig control script that it generates when it creates the generated rig.  that script isn't exported with fbx and so won't be available in the fbx file when you reimport.

Comment: I see, so if I wanted to send this rig to someone, I'll have to provide the .blend project instead.