# 'Missing bones error' when exporting FXB moel to plask.ai, Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Tags: export, bones, error

I have already tried numerous seettings and having no luck. i have added a skeleton and rigged it to my character and exported as FXB file. This file is supported by plask.ai... i will attatch the error along with the shot of the model and setting for help. i would appreciate any assistance thanks! :)[image]

[image: screenshots of error and model in blender]

Comment: I doubt anyone here knows what "plask.ai" is and problems importing into it are off-topic here anyway, but I don't believe fbx format supports Rigify rigs anyway from the comments here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264601/imported-rigify-rig-is-broken.

Comment: thanks for your reply! i have tried also glb file and have to same issue, is there a way to add bones and mesh to the layers, as the other program only requires bones and mesh, it does not require rigs i think maybe the bones are not showing in the fxb file?

Comment: It sounds like a problem importing into your external program and we can't help with that. To check the glb and fbx files, try importing them back into an empty Blender file and see if they work as expected.